# Planar PLL2410W Monitor Working for Dell PC but not MacBook Pro

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I'm having a small little issue with extending my laptop onto a second monitor. I have a Planar PLL2410W monitor which was currently being used with a Dell PC running Windows 7 with no problem (via VGA). I'd like to sometimes use the monitor with my MacBook Pro (latest edition, running the new macOS Sierra). Since the laptop does not come with a VGA port, I bought an HDMI-to-VGA adapter (GE brand) but the monitor displays "No signal." I have thoroughly checked all the inputs and everything and tried using the adapter on other monitors and it works fine on all of them, just except the Planar monitor.

Any suggestions/ thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the adapter model number and revision (if available).

Comment: @user186658 sorry I thought the adapter information was less important; the model is 33588 (it's this one here: https://www.walmart.com/ip/GE-HDMI-to-VGA-Adapter/52162868)

Comment: You may need to install drivers for the adapter. Windows may natively recognize it, whereas OSX might not.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf even if it works for other monitors? It's just the Planar one giving me problems

Comment: There's a slight possibility it's a VGA to HDMI converter, not vice versa. I haven't heard of it being a feature but it's possible some manufacturers have started integrating the ability to accept a digital signal over VGA.
In shortened form, you're going to need a different adapter. I recommend Startech.com for something like this, I've contacted them before on very specific items and use-cases and they were able to find something.